# annotation processor: how to verity method return type is Map<Foo,Bar>

Tags: java, return-type, annotation-processing

How to verify a method's return type is Map with type parameters Foo and Bar?

```
public Map<Foo, Bar> getValue();

public void verify(ExecutableElement method) {
     TypeMirror returnType = method.getReturnType();
     // how to verify return type is Map<Foo,Bar>

}
```

Foo and Bar can be primitive type, user-defined type or java types( in java.* and javax.* packages). This question actually is: how to check a TypeMirror is `Map<Foo,Bar>`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is an easier way, but the following works.

```
public void verify(ExecutableElement method) {

    DeclaredType declaredMethod = (DeclaredType) method;
    Elements elementUtils = processingEnv.getElementUtils();

    TypeMirror mapType = elementUtils.getTypeElement("java.util.Map").asType();
    TypeMirror typeArg1 = elementUtils.getTypeElement("path.to.Foo").asType();
    TypeMirror typeArg2 = elementUtils.getTypeElement("path.to.Bar").asType();

    boolean equalMainType = declaredMethod.asElement().asType().equals(mapType);
    Iterator<? extends TypeMirror> iterator = declaredMethod.getTypeArguments().iterator();
    boolean typeArgRes1 = iterator.next().equals(typeArg1);
    boolean typeArgRes2 = iterator.next().equals(typeArg2);

    if (equalMainType && typeArgRes1 && typeArgRes2) {
        // Type matches
    }
}
```